# Which impact has the "layer_coordinate_transform_info"-tag in the QGIS-project file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS there is a persistent bug which causes that the project file gets cluttered with old entrys in the "layer_coordinate_transform_info"-tag of layers which are not present in the project file anymore.

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/14733

At the moment I am cleaning old project files and also had to deal with entries which pointed to old destDatumTransform-ID's which did not exist in my srs.db anymore. These entries were also not updated when saving the project.
So I think this are two bugs in QGIS (not removing old entries and not updating entries).

As long as everyone who uses the project file has set the proper options in this section i would expect QGIS to use these settings:

[image]

Instead it seems that QGIS uses the entries of the project files "layer_coordinate_transform_info"-section even if the destDatumTransform-ID's used in the project file don't exist any more in the srs.db, so layers are displaced without any error message.

Is this a QGIS-bug? And is it save to just delete this section of the project file?